# EF 4.1 Code First Mapping Problem

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

All my attempts to map the ID of SitePage to the database column ID (SitePages table, ID column of type bigint) has failed. It keeps looking for column SitePage_ID to map it.. Can you see where I am doing wrong? All related code is below;

```
public class Site : EntityBase<Int64>
{
    public virtual string Url { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<SitePage> Pages { get; set; }
}

public class SitePage : EntityBase<Int64>
{
    public virtual Site Site { get; set; }

    public virtual string Url { get; set; }
    public virtual string Html { get; set; }
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual string Language { get; set; }
}

public abstract class EntityBase<T> : IComparable
{

    public virtual T ID { get; set; }

    protected EntityBase() : this(default(T)) 
    { 
    }

    protected EntityBase(T id)
    {
        this.ID = id;

        if (this.ID == null)
            this.ID = default(T);
    }
}

public class SpellCrawlerContext : DbContext
{
    public SpellCrawlerContext(){}

    public DbSet<Site> Sites { get; set; }

    public DbSet<SitePage> SitePages { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Site>()
            .HasMany(s => s.Pages)
            .WithRequired(p => p.Site)
            .Map(s => s.MapKey("SiteID"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<SitePage>()
            .HasKey(p => p.ID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<SitePage>()
            .Property(p => p.ID)
            .HasColumnName("ID");

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify the table layout you are expecting? The code you have generates a Site_ID column on the SitePages table, but no SitePage_ID column on either table.

Comment: I used the code you provided and let EF generate the database schema. It generated the schema properly and I had no errors. Could there be anything missing in the sample code provided?

Comment: I am not having EF generate tables.. I am connecting to existing db. Basically each table has ID column as the primary key/identity column. The ID on EntitiyBase maps directly to the ID column of each table. EF for some reason expects a SitePage_ID column eventhough I tell it explicitly to map the ID property of SitePage class to ID column on OnModelCreating.. I guess I am doing it wrong but I don't know where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. The code you shown does everything correctly. You even don't need to explicitly define the name of `ID` in `SitePage` because it will be defined like `ID` anyway.

`SitePage_ID` is used by default naming convention for foreign keys created for independent associations. So do you have any other one-to-many relation between `SitePage` and any other entity? If you didn't map foreign key in dependent entity it will be defined as `SitePage_ID` by default.

Comment: Thanks Ladislav, I had public virtual IList<SitePage> ChildPages { get; set; } on SitePage which was the cause..